Evaluating the principal value integral $\operatorname{Pr}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dt}{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}t$
I have this principal value integral that I want to solve.
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Pr}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dt}{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}t
\end{align}
Since there is a singularity at $t=x$ (which is supposed to lie within $(a,b)$), this integral is essentially the sum of the following two integrals
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\left[\int_{a}^{x-\epsilon}\frac{dt}{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}t+\int_{x+\epsilon}^{b}\frac{dt}{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}t\right].
\end{align}
I thought of taking $t=e^{i\theta}$ but because of the square root in the numerator I am unable to solve this integral. If you can suggest some other way or steps I would be grateful.

$$I(x,a,b)=\frac1\pi\int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}t\,dt$$
$$=-\frac x\pi \int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}\,dt-\frac1\pi\int_a^b\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}\,dt=I_1+I_2\tag{1}$$
Making the substitution $\,t=a+(b-a)s\,$ and denoting $\,\displaystyle c=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$
$$I_2=-\frac1\pi\int_a^b\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}\,dt=-\frac{(b-a)^2}\pi\int_0^1\sqrt{s(1-s)}ds=-\frac{(b-a)^2}8\tag{2}$$
$$I_1=-\frac x\pi \int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}{x-t}\,dt=-\frac{x(b-a)}\pi\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{(s(1-s)}}{s-c}ds$$
$$\overset{t=\frac1s}{=}-\frac{x(b-a)}{\pi c}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt t}{(1+t)^2}\,\frac{dt}{t-\frac{1-c}c}$$
Using the keyhole contour in the complex plane (with added two small arches - above $z=\frac{1-c}c$ on the upper bank of the cut, and below - on the lower bank)
$$2I_1+I_{C_1}+I_{C_2}=-\frac{2\pi i\,x(b-a)}{\pi c}\underset{z=e^{\pi i}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\sqrt z}{(1+z)^2}\,\frac1{z-\frac{1-c}c}$$
Integrals along the small arches ($I_{C_1}+I_{C_2}$) cancel each other. Evaluating the residue at $z=e^{\pi i}$
$$2I_1=-2x(b-a)\Big(c-\frac12\Big)\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,I_1=x\,\frac{2x-b-a}2\tag{3}$$
Putting (2) and (3) into (1)
$$\boxed{\,\,I(x, a, b)=-\frac{(b-a)^2}8+x\,\frac{2x-b-a}{2}\,\,}$$

Thank you so much for your detailed answer but I am not able to understand why you are taking the Residue at $z=e^{i\pi}=-1$. The integral, after the change of variables, is from $0$ to $\infty$, so isn't $z= -1$ outside the contour? On the other hand, why aren't you considering residue at $z=\frac{1-c}{c}\geq0$?

The keyhole contour means integration along the upper bank of the cut-  from $0$ to $R,(R\to\infty$ ; the cut is $[0;\infty))$, then integration along the big circle of the radius $R\to\infty$ (counter-clockwise), and then integration from $R$ to $0$ along the lower bank of the cut. The point $z=-1 (e^{-\pi i})$ is inside the closed contour

Okay I think I understand now. Thank you so much!!
